# Running Vim in GNU Screen: How to avoid Shift+left/right to delete characters

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I found that `Shift+left` and `Shift+right` delete characters,

when running `Vim` inside a `GNU Screen` session.

The same is true for `Ctrl+Shift+left` and `Ctrl+Shift+right`.

Usually, these combination are related to highlighting text and not to deleting text.

What is happening and how can it be repaired?

Comment: This sounds like a `TERM` or key-mapping issue to me - BTW, `<S-Left>` and `<S-Right>` don't highlight in vim, but work like `b` and `w` respectively (i.e. move the cursor one word to the left or right) but it shouldn't delete any characters. I get something similar when I try those key combos with `screen`, also. I _don't_ get the same behaviour in `tmux`, however, which I highly recommend over `screen` :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run `screen` with a different `TERM`, such as `xterm`, e.g.

```
$ screen -T xterm
...
```

Comment: By the way, Neovim does not appear to have this issue and works without modifying the `TERM`